# How do you prevent Vim from showing an at symbol (@) when a line doesn't fit on screen?

Tags: vim, settings, vi

In Vim, when I have a line that can not be entirely shown on screen, the line appears as an at symbol "@" all the way down to the bottom of the screen.  For example, if I have a file as such:

```
1 Hello World
2 Really long sentence 
  that doesn't fit on 
  one line.
```

And I am at the beginning of the document, with a screen height of 3 lines, Vim shows the following:

```
1 Hello World
@
@
```

I would rather have Vim show the following:

```
1 Hello World
2 Really long sentence
  that doesn't fit on
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add `set display+=lastline` to your `~/.vimrc`

From `:help 'display'`:

```
lastline        When included, as much as possible of the last line
                in a window will be displayed.  When not included, a 
                last line that doesn't fit is replaced with "@" lines.
```

Answer (score 7):

`:set display=lastline` will make it look like this:

```
2 Really long sentence
  that doesn't fit @@@
```